# Python Selenium Chromewebdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, info

I have just tried an old code of 2020 from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocweEorBrmU)
of implementation in python of Selenium and Chrome drivers. When the program starts it gives lots of warnings of "deprecated version". (I also scanned webdriver file with TotalVirus and it seems have 1 virus, is it possible?)

I'd like to ask if anyone knows a recent book/good video/tutorial where to find good notes without risk my computer life XD.

If yr asking, I'd like to use and learn Selenium with python actually to make programs of data analysis on social medias (ex. control of new/deleted followers etc...).
If u know better options, don't mind to tell them to me :)
Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a recent book or tutorial on Selenium with Python, but you can try looking for one online. As for the warnings, I'm not sure if they're anything to worry about, but you can try scanning the webdriver file with a virus scanner just to be safe.

Comment: I didn't understand, did you use chrome driver from source code of tutorial or you downloaded it from [official link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org)

Comment: Thank You Mohamed! I'm gonna look online a bit and maybe this time a install the webdriver from the official link with virus scanner!!!